# Change Color/other values of JPanel located in a GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, gridbaglayout

I've inserted a few JPanels in a GridBagLayout, with the gridBagConstraints object,
and after a specific action I want to change the color of some JPanels.
My question is how do I access the specific JPanels in the GridBagLayout and change their colors.
(with given coordinates of the Jpanels in the grid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign those JPanels to some sort of variable in order to be able to get a reference to them. This could be individual variables, or a collection such as a List or Map. If you haven't yet used Maps, then I would recommend that you give careful towards using these very helpful constructs which can allow you to gain access to an object based on a String, their "coordinates" or some other unique identifier.

As an aside, my suggestion obviously has nothing to do with the layout manager, and I don't think that trying to use the layout manager for this will lead to a robust long-term solution.

If you must get the GridBagConstraints for an individual component in the GridBagLayout-using container, per the [GridBagLayout API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) you could use the GridBagLayout method, `public GridBagConstraints getConstraints(Component comp)`. If you needed this for all components, then you could call `getComponents()` on your container, iterate through all the Components in a for loop, calling the above method on them.

Also, if you need more specific help, then consider editing your question by creating and posting a [minimal code example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to review, test, and possibly help you fix.